# Memoization in Recursion solution for the probelm SPIDY2

Tags: python, recursion, memoization

I am trying to learn Dynamic Programming, but stuck in a problem, where I can't make the solution using memoization with recursion. The link to the problem is

https://www.codechef.com/problems/SPIDY2

I have implemented a recursive solution, but could not understand how to make it more efficient.

```
import math

n = int(input())
h = list(map(int, input().split()))

dp = [float('inf')]*(n)

def helper(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n < 0:
        return float('inf')
    else:
        for i in range(n-1, -1, -1):
            if math.log(n-i, 2).is_integer():
                dp[n] = min(dp[n], abs(h[n]-h[i])+helper(i))
        return dp[n]

print(helper(n-1))
```

I thought that the solution would give me `TLE`, but it is giving me `Runtime Error`. I don't know why. Can someone please explain me how to build a recursion with memoization solution for the above problem ?

Also, if you know of a platform (maybe slack, gitter channels) where I can ask my coding related doubts, please do suggest me.

Comment: when you get `Runtime error`, it should also output a message. Which message is this ? If the website does not give the message, try running your code locally with a big enough `n`. I suspect that you are running into stack overflow error (pun not intended), which is when your recursion is too deep

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, I tried with the maximum constraint value, 20000 and I got `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`. So how can I memoize the recursion. I can't build the logic.

Comment: you need to change your logic a little and to save time/computation you can save 2**i values in a list

Comment: the idea of memoization is to be able to return a value that was already calculated without descending into recursion again. In your case, you are running the for loop, thus `helper(i)` before you return. You should have something like `if dp[n] != inf: return dp[n]` right in the entry of the function, so that you avoid the rest of the calculation

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă But this line `dp[n] = min(dp[n], abs(h[n]-h[i])+helper(i))` calls the helper() function many times. Each time value is returned, it gets stored in dp[n], and if I place a condition like `if dp[n] != inf: return dp[n]`, it would never call the other remaining functions, it would simply return that same value again and again. But I want minimum of all those values. (I am a beginner in DP and recursion, so please correct me, if I interpreted something wrong)